# W3C Google Chrome Speech Synthesizer - Male Voice

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, speech

I've been using the [W3C Speech Synthesizer](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/speech-api/raw-file/tip/speechapi.html#speechsynthesisvoice) for the web in my app. I am able to set language and choose a voice. In Chinese at least, all the voices appear to be female. I believe US English is also female. Is there a way to get male voices?

I see, looping through the voices, there are Male and Female for UK English, but two female options for Mainland Chinese (`Google 中国`) and Taiwan Chinese (`Mei-Jia`):

```
speechSynthesis.getVoices().forEach(function(voice) {
    console.log(voice.name, voice.default ? '(default)' :'');
});
```

> ```
> Google US English (default)
> Google UK English Male 
> Google UK English Female 
> Google 中国的 
> Mei-Jia
> ```